# MongoDB Restore Failed

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I'm trying to restore a mongodb database from a dump in Ubuntu 14.04.2, the dump was created on MongoDB shell version: 2.4.13 and I'm restoring on MongoDB shell version: 3.0.1.

This is the command I'm running and the error I'm getting.

mongorestore /home/somename/backups/staging/mongo

2015-04-01T12:12:32.886+0200    building a list of dbs and collections to restore from /home/somename/backups/staging/mongo dir

2015-04-01T12:12:32.896+0200    assuming users in the dump directory are from <= 2.4 (auth version 1)

2015-04-01T12:12:32.896+0200    Failed: the users and roles collections in the dump have an incompatible auth version with target server: cannot restore users of auth version 1 to a server of auth version 5

Is there a way around it or a fix?

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: We are software developers, not database administrators. I nominated your question for migration to https://dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 16):

You can get around this issue by moving the `admin` directory out of the dump folder, then re-run the mongorestore command.

For example if you ran

```
mongorestore --dir ~/path/to/mongodumpdir
```

and it failed, then most likely you have an `admin` folder in there. You can move it out, and re-run the command above.

I believe, specially, it's the `system.users.bson` that's causing the problem. Since mongo `2.x.x` and `3.x.x` add and store users differently.

Of course, users from your old mongodb won't be available in your new db, but you can always manually add them back in.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add authentification database in CLI command as : 
--authenticationDatabase admin

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `--authenticationMechanism SCRAM-SHA-1`

refer to docs:
 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption--authenticationMechanism